# c# deserializing JSON web api response

Tags: c#, json, response, asp.net-web-api

I need a little help from somebody who can tell me where my mistake is.
I have an API which returns JSON code:

```
{"block4o": {
   "id": 20153910,
   "name": "Block4o",
   "profileIconId": 616,
   "revisionDate": 1408967362000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}}
```

I tried to desearialize it but without success. I am using NewtonSoft.Json from NuGet. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Program
    {

        class MyData
        {
            public long id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int profileIconId { get; set; }
            public long revisionDate { get; set; }
            public long summonerLevel { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
              "https://eune.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Block4o?api_key=****");
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();

            MyData tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(responseFromServer);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",tmp.id);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

P.S It works if the response is like this:

```
{
   "id": 20153910,
   "name": "Block4o",
   "profileIconId": 616,
   "revisionDate": 1408967362000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}
```

Comment: Paste your json to http://json2csharp.com/ and see how your classes should be declared.

Comment: Heimerdinger would know how to do it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify which property of your json corresponds to your model.

```
MyData tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>((JObject.Parse(responseFromServer)["block4o"]).ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define the class

```
public class Response
{
  public MyData Block4o { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize as Response, you should get the desired result.